# sweet stones of Perosa

Tags: baking

I saw pictures of some sweet buns that look striking, and I cannot find a recipe. The buns are described as "sweet stones of Perosa."
Here is a picture of [*sweet stones of Perosa*](https://www.comune.perosaargentina.to.it/cgi-bin/fotogallery/2019729164460.jpg), and another of [*sweet stones of Perosa in a basket*](https://www.comune.perosaargentina.to.it/cgi-bin/fotogallery/20197291644792.jpg).
How does one achieve the stone look? 
The pictures are from a web site that promotes the town of Perosa Argentia, the implication being that these are traditional bake goods from that region of Piedmont, as such, I assumed the silver coating is achieved by means accessible to a country cook. I thought may be eatable charcoal mixed with something could produce the effect, but I have no idea.

Comment: HI, Victor! Welcome to Seasoned Advice! Your current question is a little bit unclear on what you're asking - do you want to know how to achieve the stone look or do you want a recipe for this (since you mention that you don't have a recipe). Please note that recipe requests are [off-topic](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), so my suggestion would be for you to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza it doesn't look like a recipe request to me; the last sentence clearly states _How does one achieve the stone look?_

Comment: @Luciano That's done basically by following the recipe. Unless there is some specific aspect of "the stone look" OP needs addressed, this is a recipe request.

Comment: I'm not sure about the silver glaze/topping, but if you search "chocolate crackle cookie" online, you will see cookies that resemble the cracked effect that you are looking for.  You might also help us by adding more information.  I assume you are referring to Perosa, Argentina.  Is this correct?  Also, where do your images come from?

Comment: @moscafj it looks like it's Perosa Argentina, Italy, in the Piemonte region. Taken from the links.

Comment: @Luciano...ha!  Yes. My haste and lack of recognition... I was just south of there 3 weeks ago!

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza : the reason that recipe requests are forbidden is that there are often hundreds of variations for a given item.  In this case, it's a specific outcome that they're trying to achieve, so it'd count as 'restaurant mimicry', which is allowed

Comment: @Joe I would put it in the category of technique, as opposed to restaurant mimicry.

Comment: @Joe that's exactly what I've written in my comment. If there is any specific part of the look / texture / flavor that OP wants to get, that's allowed. If OP doesn't even have a recipe and wants one, that's a recipe request.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of options. I've never heard of "sweet stones of Perosa", but if the recipe actually goes back many years then it's likely it originally used extremely thin silver (or other metal) foil, stuck to the buns and then baked.

Those pictures don't look like edible foil, though. The silver is attenuated at the sides. That makes me think they're using spray-on silver food coloring (basically edible spray paint).

In either case, the coloring is likely applied before baking, and as the buns puff up the colored area cracks, making the buns look rocky rather than just silver.

Answer (score 0):

A crackle or crinkle cookie is created with a specific recipe, and then individual cookies are rolled into a ball for baking.  The ball is then, most commonly, rolled into powdered sugar.  The nature of the dough is such that when baking, the cracks form, and the sugar highlights these irregularities. I don't know for certain, but I would guess that this is what you have pictured.  Admittedly, however, I am stumped by the silver topping.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question is more about the silver coating.